# How to replace NA values in a column with data from the adjacent column?

Tags: r

This is how it looks like:

```
   Maths   Rank
    Good      1
VeryGood      2
       3     NA
       4     NA
       5     NA
```

This is how it should look:

```
   Maths   Rank
    Good      1
VeryGood      2
      NA      3
      NA      4
      NA      5
```

Comment: [This is how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry Richard.. I am new here...

Comment: It's okay.  Welcome!  What you really need to include here is an explanation of exactly what you're trying to do.  It looks like you just want to swap the numerics across to the next column.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the data frame having some 300 rows of entries. What i am trying to do is to fill some rows in column "Rank"  that has the values "na" by values stored in adjacent column "maths". This is because the data is tilda delimited and MATHS  column is empty.  also i know it can be easily edited in notepad. but i wanted to know the process in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Maths <- c("Good", "VeryGood", 3, 4, 5)
Rank <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA)
test <- cbind(Maths,Rank)
test
for (i in 1:length(Rank)){
Rank[i] <- ifelse(is.na(Rank[i]),Maths[i],Rank[i])
Maths[i] <- ifelse(Maths[i]==Rank[i],NA,Maths[i])
}
test <- cbind(Maths,Rank)
test
```

-EDIT-
see scoa's comment*

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can vectorize this solution : `Rank <- ifelse(is.na(Rank),Maths,Rank) ; 
Maths <- ifelse(Maths==Rank,NA,Maths)
`

Answer (score 1):

We could do this without a loop.  We create a logical index for the 'NA' values in 'Rank' column (`is.na(df1$Rank)`).  Using that, we can replace the 'NA' values in 'Rank' with the corresponding values in 'Maths'.  In the last step, replace the 'Maths' values corresponding to 'NA' based on 'indx'.

```
  indx <- is.na(df1$Rank)
  df1$Rank[indx] <- df1$Maths[indx]
  df1$Maths[indx] <- NA
  df1
  #     Maths Rank
  #1     Good    1
  #2 VeryGood    2
  #3     <NA>    3
  #4     <NA>    4
  #5     <NA>    5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Maths = c("Good", "VeryGood", "3", "4", "5"), 
Rank = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Maths", "Rank"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to akrun's approach. The only difference it is that here the columns are swapped when the condition is met:

```
test[is.na(test$Rank), ] <- test[is.na(test$Rank), c(2,1)]
```

or for clarity:

```
index <- is.na(test$Rank)
test[index, ] <- test[index, c(2, 1)]
```

Output:

```
     Maths Rank
1     Good    1
2 VeryGood    2
3     <NA>    3
4     <NA>    4
5     <NA>    5
```

Data:

```
Maths <- c("Good", "VeryGood", 3, 4, 5)
Rank <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA)
test <- data.frame(Maths,Rank, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @akrun Sorry, that's true. The only difference, I think, it is that you assign NA based on the index whereas in my code I just swap columns where the condition is met. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I noticed that now.  Looks cool!  I assigned it separately to be a bit more clear.